# Can CDNs handle base64 encoded data?

Tags: image-processing, upload, xmlhttprequest, base64, cdn

I'm trying to make an app where I take pictures from users add them to a canvas, draw stuff in them, then convert them to a base64 string and upload them.
For this purpose I'm considering the possibility to use a cdn but can't find information on what I can upload to them and how the client side uploading works. I'd like to be able to send the image as base64 and the name to be given to the file, so that when it arrives to the origin cdn, the base64 image is decoded and saved under the specified name (which I will add to the database on the server).
Is this possible?
Can I have some kind of save.php file on the origin cdn where I write my logic to save the file and to which I'll send XHR requests? Or how this whole thing work?
I know this question may sound trivial but I'm looking for it for hours and still didn't find anything which explains in detail how the client side uploading work for CDNs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

CDNs usually do not provide such uploading service for client side, so you can not do it in this way.

Comment: Does this means that anybody who resizes, modifies images client side before upload cannot use a cdn?

Comment: CDN only used to provide content downloading from client side. In your case,  you need upload files from client side to your web server firstly, then your web server could deploy these new content to CDN, at last, client side could download these new content from CDN.